# Can I use a 1600 MHz DDR3 stick on a motherboard that supports max 1333 MHz memory modules?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr

Is that possible? Would it be possible to simply run the 1600 MHz module on a slower speed (e.g. 1333 MHz)?

Comment: See this post: http://superuser.com/questions/753502/what-happens-if-i-use-ram-of-a-faster-speed-than-the-cpu-supports

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. This is asking about MB support, not CPU support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will run at the lower speed, 1333 Mhz.